# Conditional event doesn't trigger with complex expressions

Tags: camunda

I have a question about the conditional events. Does it validate only simple expressions like count > 5 or flag === true or it can validate a complex expression as well ? something like given below

```
${execution.getVariable("Flags").ABCCheckStart == true}
```

Because, I set the ABCCheckStart flag to true using below script :

```
var temp=JSON.parse(Flags);
temp.ABCCheckStart = true;

execution.setVariable("Flags", S(JSON.stringify(temp)));
```

and then I put below expression to validate the condition :

```
${execution.getVariable("Flags").ABCCheckStart == true}
```

But the conditional event doesn't trigger. Am I missing something here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the process model, but assume you are setting the data in an earlier step and later the process reaches the conditional event ( - or is there already a token at the conditional event when you write the data?).

A conditional event only gets evaluated when it has a token and the specified variable gets created or updated (or both, depending on what you specified).

When the event triggers, the expression is evaluated in the (Spring) context. It can be complex, access Beans, etc.

Btw, you don't need to use getVariable("Flags"). Process data can be resolved directly by id.